# How to take screen-quality screenshots in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, screenshot

Recently, I needed to take a screenshot of a long browser page (~8 pg.s), consisting of an important document, so, using Firefox, I immediately turned to the addons page thinking there must be a neat solution somewhere.

However, it turns out that *every single screenshot addon for Firefox* takes screenshots at an incredibly low resolution. This might be because I am using a Macbook with a high pixel-density Retina screen. Still, the results speak for themselves [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSLR1.jpg), where I first took a regular screenshot of a page with my OS, followed by the addon's screenshot (though all 4 addons I found exhibited the same behavior).

So, is there an addon I'm missing that actually works, or is there a neat trick to taking screenshots In Firefox that I do not know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox DevTools can take screen-quality screenshot (tested with Windows Firefox).

Comment: Would've been nice to have more details given in this answer, but implementing this is truly easy and my first google search revealed what I was looking for here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Taking_screenshots

It would, however, be nice not to have to open Firefox developer tools each time you need to take a single screenshot, instead of clicking an easily accessible addon button, but that is a vain hope! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can try Firefox native screenshots https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-screenshots.